# Operaciones con arrays

Tags: c#, array, matrices

Tengo una matriz de 3 filas por 5 columnas( que son tipo reglas)

```
a^b=c
d^e=f
g^h=j
```

Donde:

```
Matriz[0,0]="a"
Matriz[0,1]="^"
Matriz[0,2]="b"
Matriz[0,3]="="
Matriz[0,4]="c"
```

.
.
.

```
Matriz[2,4]="j"
```

Y por ejemplo ingreso los valores en un árray: a y b
Entonces como a y b están en Matriz  que salga el resultado que es c.
En caso ingreso sólo a. Entonces no podrá votarle c, porque falta b.

Gracias!!

Comment: no entendi, quieres imprimir esa formula o esos a y b en realidad son valores numerico que quiere aplicar una formula? Si un valo falta ingresar lo validas y muestras un mensaje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no entendí mal tu duda, puedes implementar un método que te devuelva el resultado dado los valores. En otras palabras un método que tenga como parametros dos strings y que te devuelva el string resultado según la matriz.

```
    public string getResult(string x, string y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (x == Matriz[i, 0] && y == Matriz[i, 2])
                return Matriz[i, 4];
        }
        return "¡Valor no encontrado!";
    }
```

Este es el método. Como ves sus parametros son los dos valores strings. Mediante un bucle **for** este itera por cada fila de la matriz (Dimensión 0) y por medio de un **if** inspecciona si el primer string **x** es igual al elemento **0** de la fila de la matriz y lo mismo para el segundo string **y** con el elemento **2**. Como el resultado se encuentra en el elemento 4 de la fila, si la condición se cumple, podemos retornar el valor string en dicho elemento.

Si itera por todas las filas y nunca se cumple la condición simplemente retorna un mensaje de que el valor no se encontró.

Comment: Muchas gracias solucionó mi problema